# Overloading + Operator to take a line(Two coordinates*2) + a point(Two coordinates)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class called OnePoint consisting of two double values, my two coordinates, x and y. I have a class Line consisting of two "OnePoint's" - As two points are a line. I also have a class Polygon consisting of 3 "OnePoint's" put into a vector - As a Polygon has 3 or more points.

Here is my function that is supposed to do exactly that.

```
Polygon operator+(const OnePoint &lhs, const Line &rhs) {
    Polygon retvalu; 
    retvalu.inputvector(lhs); 
    retvalu.inputvector(rhs.getonevalue); //Line 150
    retvalu.inputvector(rhs.gettwovalue); //Line 151
    return retvalu;
}
```

Error code on line 150 and line 151:

```
non-standard syntax; use '&' to create pointer to member
```

All of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class OnePoint {
private:
    double xvalue;
    double yvalue;

public:
    OnePoint(double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0) {
        xvalue = x;
        yvalue = y;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& printh, OnePoint& cPoint) {
        printh << "(" << cPoint.xvalue << ',' << cPoint.yvalue << ")";
        return printh;

    }

    void Plus(OnePoint a) {
        xvalue = xvalue + a.xvalue;
        yvalue = yvalue + a.yvalue;
    }

    void Minus(OnePoint b) {

        xvalue = xvalue + b.xvalue;
        yvalue = yvalue + b.yvalue;

    }

    OnePoint Plustwo(OnePoint a) {
        return (xvalue + a.xvalue, yvalue - a.yvalue);

    }

    void Change(double a, double b) {
        xvalue += a;
        yvalue += b;
    }

    void Print(OnePoint b) {

        cout << xvalue << "," << yvalue << endl;

    }

    /*OnePoint operator-(OnePoint a) {
        OnePoint temp;
        temp.xvalue = xvalue + a.xvalue;
        temp.yvalue = yvalue + a.yvalue;

        return temp;

        }


        friend OnePoint operator+(OnePoint a, OnePoint b) {
        OnePoint temp;
        temp.xvalue = a.xvalue + b.xvalue;
        temp.yvalue = a.yvalue + b.yvalue;

        return temp;

        }*/
};

class Line {
private:
    OnePoint onevalue;
    OnePoint twovalue;
public:
    Line(OnePoint a = OnePoint(), OnePoint b = OnePoint()) {
        onevalue = a;
        twovalue = b;

    }

    OnePoint getonevalue() {
        return onevalue;
    }

    OnePoint gettwovalue() {

        return twovalue;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& print, Line& cLine) {
        print << "{" << cLine.onevalue << ',' << cLine.twovalue << "}";
        return print;
    }

    /*friend Line operator+(OnePoint a, OnePoint b) {
        Line temp(a, b);
        return temp;
        }*/
};

class Polygon {
private:
    vector <OnePoint> polly;
public:
    Polygon(OnePoint a = OnePoint(), OnePoint b = OnePoint(), OnePoint c = OnePoint()) {
        polly.push_back(a);
        polly.push_back(b);
        polly.push_back(c);
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& print, Polygon& pollyclass) {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < pollyclass.polly.size(); i++) {
            print << pollyclass.polly[i];
        }

        return print;
    }

    void outputvector() {

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < polly.size(); i++) {
            cout << polly[i];
        }


    }

    void inputvector(OnePoint a) {
        polly.push_back(a);
    }
};

Line operator+(const OnePoint &lhs, const OnePoint &rhs){
    Line retval(lhs, rhs);
    return retval;
}

Polygon operator+(const OnePoint &lhs, const Line &rhs){
    Polygon retvalu;
    retvalu.inputvector(lhs);
    retvalu.inputvector(rhs.getonevalue); //Line 150
    retvalu.inputvector(rhs.gettwovalue); //Line 151

    return retvalu;
}

/*Polygon operator+(const Line &lhs, const OnePoint &rhs)
{
Polygon retval(rhs, lhs.getonevalue, lhs.gettwovalue);

return retval;
}*/

Polygon operator+(const Polygon &lhs, const Polygon &rhs) {
}

int main() {
    OnePoint a(3.0, 3.0);
    OnePoint b(1.0, 1.0);
    OnePoint y(3.0, 4.0);
    OnePoint i(4.0, 2.0);
    OnePoint p(3.0, 4.0);
    OnePoint m(4.0, 2.0);

    Line d(a, b);
    Polygon j(a, b, y);
    Polygon h(i, p, b);
    Polygon w;
    Line o;
    o = a + b;

    w = b + o;
    cout << w;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << d << endl;
    cout << o << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error VS gives me is clear:

```
error C3867: 'Line::getonevalue': function call missing argument list ...
```

`getonevalue` and `gettwovalue` are functions, so you need to add parentheses to call them:

```
Polygon operator+(const OnePoint &lhs, const Line &rhs) {
    Polygon retvalu;
    retvalu.inputvector(lhs);
    retvalu.inputvector(rhs.getonevalue()); //Line 150
    retvalu.inputvector(rhs.gettwovalue()); //Line 151
    return retvalu;
}
```

Now, we get another error. The compiler complains because these functions aren't const-qualified, yet you try to call them on non-const instance `rhs`. They don't modify the object, just return a copy to a member variable. Make them const-qualified:

```
OnePoint getonevalue() const {
    return onevalue; 
}
```

And don't forget to implement `Polygon operator+(const Polygon&, const Polygon&)`.

In addition, this code requires `OnePoint` to be constructible with one argument and it's wrong:

```
OnePoint Plustwo(OnePoint a) {
    return (xvalue + a.xvalue, yvalue - a.yvalue);
}
```

This uses comma operator, which translates to this:

```
OnePoint Plustwo(OnePoint a) {
    xvalue + a.xvalue;
    return yvalue - a.yvalue;
}
```

- this requires implicit conversion from `double` to `OnePoint`, it's simply messed up. Solution is [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (C++11) or a standard construction:

```
OnePoint Plustwo(OnePoint a) {
    return {xvalue + a.xvalue, yvalue - a.yvalue}; // list initialization
}

OnePoint Plustwo(OnePoint a) {
    return OnePoint(xvalue + a.xvalue, yvalue - a.yvalue);
}
```

With this, `Line`'s constructor has to use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Line(OnePoint a, OnePoint b) : onevalue(a), twovalue(b)
{
}
```

What you had was default construction and assignment, not copy-assignment. I guess this is all I can advise, the `Polygon` default constructor is required by `operator+` and you're default-constructing `Line` in main, so you'll have to add a default constructor anyway.

Comment: Ohgod, I keep forgetting the parenthesis. Thanks dude. I really appreciate the help. I kinda foresaw this output and yes I am getting (0.0)(0.0)(0.0)(3.2)(3.4)(3.2), (I should get (3.2)(3.4)(3.2) only) for example.  Is there a way that I can get rid of the default constructor created coordinates? Or maybe overwrite.. mmhm i will take a look

Comment: About all the functions in my OnePoint class. That is just me messing around. It's not needed, and I will probably remove it. Or, maybe I will edit them later.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely give you your thumbs up if you choose to respond to this or not. But I was wondering about how I can remove (0.0)(0.0)(0.0). maybe something can be done in the operator+ function for example

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d6f7fe7b2ddf5e15cdd23506d71ec210 This is just a picture. When i write Polygon w; and because I have default constructor it will add (0.0)(0.0)(0.0), and then I will push back the other points. so It becomes (0.0)(0.0)(0.0)(4.2,3.1)(3.2,3.2)(3.0,3.0) for example.

Comment: You should not use default arguments so much. Prefer overloads. Define a default constructor for `Polygon` that doesn't add any points to `polly` and change the old one to `Polygon(OnePoint a, OnePoint b, OnePoint c)`. That way, you can construct `Polygon` with 0 or 3 points. If you want to have `Polygon` to be constructible with an arbitrary number of points, you can pass `std::vector<OnePoint>`.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I thought it wouldn't work as when I tried something similar earlier I got an error code, saying that I needed default parameters. I didn't think that when I was writing Polygon w; it would be able to know which constructor I wanted it to use.